# Where Clause return error LAMBDA EXPRESSION QUERY

Tags: entity-framework

I have this

```
var myvar = _context.Person.Include(u => u.oneByNavigation).Include(u => u.twoNavigation);

 if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(searchString))
            {
                myvar = dbContext.Where(s => s.Fname.Contains(searchString));// 
                dbContext.Where(u => u.Fname.Contains(searchString) || 
                 u.Lname.Contains(searchString));
            }
```

I am getting the error

*

> Cannot implicity convert the type system.linq.IQuerable to
>   Microsoft.EntityframeworkCore.Query.IIncludableQuerable

*

Answer (score 1):

Instead of `var myvar = _context.Person[...]`, try `IQueriable<Person> myvar = _context.Person[...]`.

If you check the type of myvar, you'll see it's not an IQuariable, but an `IIncludableQuerable`.

Answer (score 0):

hmm you are overrideng the value of `myvar`.
Try this

```
IQueriable<Person> myvar = _context.Person.Include(u => u.oneByNavigation).Include(u => u.twoNavigation);

 if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(searchString))
            {
                myvar = myvar // <-- not dbContext
                        .Where(s => s.Fname.Contains(searchString));
            }
```